# Why does editing the CSS file not automatically live update like JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webstorm

I have problem where I am developing a website and development is very difficulty and slow because editing the CSS file for classes do not make the website register the changes unless I reset the application by running `npm start`.

However when I edit any JavaScript code, the website will live update.
I am using React and WebStorm to create my website. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your configuration and code and everything. It could be many things. The only thing I can say is the configuration isn't correct so the system doesn't notice it has changed.

Comment: Your problem is not directly related to CSS or React. It is more about your Webpack config (if you are using it) and how you setup HMR.

Comment: What host/software you use to host a site?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing out your cache after edit.

Windows:

```
CTRL + F5
```

Mac:

```
CMD + SHIFT + R
```

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of live reload?

Comment: @Ferrybig what are you talking about?

Comment: If you have to manually refresh, you don't really use the live update/reload function, You are not answering the question of the OP, you are just suggesting a work around, not explaining the original problem

Comment: @Ferrybig if you can do it better then answer this question. .. Just trying to help.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it did not help :/

Comment: @J.Doe :( if you are using Chrome try Ctrl + Shift + R

Answer (score -1):

**Google Chrome** :

- Open DevTools
- Open Settings (bottom right or use F1 shortcut)
- Check Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#general

---

**mozilla Firefox** :

- Open a new window or tab in Firefox.
- Type about:config in the address bar.
- Search for “cache” in the search bar and look for
  network.http.use-cache in the filtered results.
- Double-click it will toggle it from “true” to “false”. Default should
  be “true”.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232148

---

**Opera**

- open Inspector
- click on the Network tab at the top of the panel
- click Disable cache

https://forums.opera.com/topic/25089/disabling-cache-in-51-0/3